# Trouble configuring Nginx with puppet/nginx module using Hiera

Tags: ssl, nginx, yaml, puppet, hiera

I'm trying to configure Nginx with puppet/nginx module from forge.puppet.com (by Vox Pupuli), using this Hiera yaml file:

```
nginx::nginx_servers:
    'devops-alldomains':
        server_name:
            - '~^(?<fqdn>.+?)$'
        www_root: '/var/www/$fqdn'
        index_files:
            - 'index.php'
        try_files:
            - '$uri'
            - '$uri/'
            - '/index.php?$args'
        access_log: '/var/log/nginx/devops-alldomains-access.log'
        error_log: '/var/log/nginx/devops-alldomains-error.log'
    'devops-alldomains-ssl':
        server_name:
            - '~^(?<fqdn>.+?)$'
        listen_port: '443'
        www_root: '/var/www/$fqdn'
        ssl: true
        ssl_key: '/etc/ssl/www/$fqdn.key'
        ssl_cert: '/etc/ssl/www/$fqdn.crt'
        index_files:
            - 'index.php'
        try_files:
            - '$uri'
            - '$uri/'
            - '/index.php?$args'
        access_log: '/var/log/nginx/devops-alldomains-access-ssl.log'
        error_log: '/var/log/nginx/devops-alldomains-error-ssl.log'
nginx::nginx_locations:
    'devops-alldomains':
        location: '~ \.php$'
        www_root: '/var/www/$fqdn'
        server: 'devops-alldomains'
        fastcgi: 'unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock'
        fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
        fastcgi_index: 'index.php'
        fastcgi_param:
            'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '$document_root$fastcgi_script_name'
    'devops-alldomains-ssl':
        location: '~ \.php$'
        www_root: '/var/www/$fqdn'
        server: 'devops-alldomains-ssl'
        fastcgi: 'unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock'
        fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
        fastcgi_index: 'index.php'
        fastcgi_param:
            'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '$document_root$fastcgi_script_name'
```

BUT when it generates two Nginx configs (devops-alldomains.conf and devops-alldomains-ssl.conf), the SSL one is not as expected:

```
   location / {
     root      /var/www/$fqdn;
     index     index.php;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }

   location ~ \.php$ {
     root          /var/www/$fqdn;
     include       /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;

     fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
   }
 # MANAGED BY PUPPET
 server {
   listen       *:443 ssl;
   server_name  ~^(?<fqdn>.+?)$;

   ssl on;

   ssl_certificate           /etc/ssl/www/$fqdn.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key       /etc/ssl/www/$fqdn.key;
   ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:10m;
   ssl_session_timeout       5m;
   ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers               ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE- RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-       AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-   GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS;
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

   index  index.php;

   access_log            /var/log/nginx/devops-alldomains-access-ssl.log combined;
   error_log             /var/log/nginx/devops-alldomains-error-ssl.log;

   location / {
     root      /var/www/$fqdn;
     index     index.php;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }
 }
```

So as you can see, location directives are outside of server directive, so Nginx will never start. Has anyone an idea what could be wrong? I even tried to simplify this configuration to use only basic directives (even without ssl and php) but the result was quite the same. Thanks a lot for your help.

**UPDATE:**

It looks I managed to resolve the problem with your help guys ;) This is the current config:

```
 nginx::nginx_servers:
     'devops-alldomains':
         server_name:
             - '~^(?<fqdn>.+?)$'
         www_root: '/var/www/$fqdn'
         index_files:
             - 'index.php'
         try_files:
             - '$uri'
             - '$uri/'
             - '/index.php?$args'
         access_log: '/var/log/nginx/devops-alldomains-access.log'
         error_log: '/var/log/nginx/devops-alldomains-error.log'
     'devops-alldomains-ssl':
         server_name:
             - '~^(?<fqdn>.+?)$'
         listen_port: '443'
         ssl_port: '443'
         www_root: '/var/www/$fqdn'
         ssl: true
         ssl_key: '/etc/ssl/www/$fqdn.key'
         ssl_cert: '/etc/ssl/www/$fqdn.crt'
         index_files:
             - 'index.php'
         try_files:
             - '$uri'
             - '$uri/'
             - '/index.php?$args'
         access_log: '/var/log/nginx/devops-alldomains-access-ssl.log'
         error_log: '/var/log/nginx/devops-alldomains-error-ssl.log'
 nginx::nginx_locations:
     'devops-alldomains-loc':
         location: '~ \.php$'
         www_root: '/var/www/$fqdn'
         server: 'devops-alldomains'
         fastcgi: 'unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock'
         fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
         fastcgi_index: 'index.php'
         fastcgi_param:
             'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '$document_root$fastcgi_script_name'
     'devops-alldomains-ssl-loc':
         location: '~ \.php$'
         www_root: '/var/www/$fqdn'
         server: 'devops-alldomains-ssl'
         ssl: true
         ssl_only: true
         fastcgi: 'unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock'
         fastcgi_split_path: '^(.+\.php)(/.*)$'
         fastcgi_index: 'index.php'
         fastcgi_param:
             'SCRIPT_FILENAME': '$document_root$fastcgi_script_name'
```

Now I have two separated Nginx config files - one for non-SSL, second for SSL. First problem was that I was missing **ssl: true** and **ssl_only: true** under the related location (devops-alldomains-ssl-loc), second was that I had to set both **listen_port: '443'** and **ssl_port: '443'** under the server directive. I have also changed names of locations, but it didn't seem to do any problems (or resolving something).

To make this complete, here are versions of tools used:

Puppet: 4.10.9
Hiera: 3.3.2
Nginx: 1.12.2-1~xenial
puppet/nginx (forge module): 0.9.0

Thank you for your help. I very appreciate it!

Comment: Don't you need to add the ssl and perhaps the ssl_only specifications to your locations?  (https://forge.puppet.com/puppet/nginx)

Comment: Thank you, this partially helped, at least in way, that "location ~ \.php$" is now inside of server block... but "location /" is still outside of it. I think (based on what I tried before) if I want to define root location in hiera, it will fail with duplicated definition, because root is defined by default.

Comment: Which versions of the module and Puppet are you using?

Comment: can you update your question with the current config and result?

Comment: I don't know what you've seen in the past, but in the current version of the module, it does not appear that class `nginx` defines *any* location (or server) resources by default.  Without fully analyzing the situation, I'm inclined to guess that the module does the right thing with that if you've not defined any locations at all, but that if you do define locations then you must define the root location.

Comment: Alternatively, you've defined two servers, so if the module were supposed to automatically assign the root location to a server then how is it supposed to know which one to pick?

Comment: I downvote from 1 to 0, b/c no response and accepted answer there since two years.